# Increasing stamina while in the office

Tags: road-bike, training, power

I started to bike again after 3 or more months of hiatus. I'm currently using a XXS Merida Scultura 300 (I previously used a Trinx R300 needed to upgrade because of the wrong geometry). Thing is I lost most of my stamina from my break (no exercise, lots of carbonated drink intake) and I also started using cleats which is kind of hard I fell a lot just from clipping out.

I am also a weekend rider. Since I go to the office every weekdays and got no more time to bike before or after work. I asked my friend how can I get back my stamina. What he suggested was to buy ankle weights and wear it every time. Do legs raise while in office and climb the stairs while skipping one step.

Question is, is this an effective method? Or you guys have more training methods while in office?

Edited: since Cadence isn't the question here but of endurance and to last more on biking long distance. Sorry question was written quickly in the office.

Comment: Heavier boots works well too, and might be more acceptable than ankle weights, which might be confused with ankle tracking bracelets.

Comment: In our office, we are lucky enough to have a set of rollers in the bike storage room.  So people can get some time in without going outside.  There's a phone there, so its excellent when on a long boring conference call.   Similarly, there are treadmill and exercycle desks available.   These might help your stamina, but not the cadence.

Comment: The exercises for stamina and cadence are kind of at odds with each other.

Comment: I think it likely that the question is really about endurance and speed, not literally cadence. In that case, the question is one about training. The tip-off is his questions about climbing stairs and ankle weights, which have very little to do with cadence per se. He's asking about ways to improve his cycling power through alternatives to cycling.

Comment: How much time do you have to ride on the weekends?

Comment: hi all, I've edited the question. And R. Chung was right about what I've wanted to ask.

Comment: You can always get a standing desk and put a treadmill under it.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to improve at riding is to ride -- but many people do have limitations on their time that make it difficult to ride as much during the week as they would like.

At one end of the spectrum, there is some amount of almost all fitness-building activity that is transferable to cycling fitness. Cycling is *mostly* an aerobic sport, so vigorously climbing stairs or vigorous lunch walks can help. Parking or getting off the bus a few blocks away from work and then walking vigorously the rest of the way can help your overall aerobic fitness.

At the other end of the spectrum, you may want to investigate purchasing (or borrowing) a magnetic or fluid trainer on which you can place your bike so you can train at home. Many people who live in cold climates who do not wish to ride outdoors or after dark in winter either train at home or in gymnasiums to good effect, and are ready to ride on the roads when spring arrives. There are training plans and software you can purchase to guide you in indoor training.

Comment: If its dark at night, there may be a window in the morning where its light enough to feel safe.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing stamina and cadence cannot be trained at the same time. Why not try going to work on your bike instead? It will help you keep fit and it is also a logical thing to do since you do have a nice bike. Plus it will also cost you less than buying ankle weights. For that is already a win-win situation.

Or if you don't want to do that. Maybe a bit of walking up and down staircases of your office will increase you anaerobic capacity. Whilst about your cadence and your trouble clipping in and out, I guess all you can really do is put more time with the bike to have a better feel of what you can do... Also try clipping in and put of your bike while holding onto something (ex. Tree, pole, or wall) then pedal backwards and try clipping in and out. If you have a hard time clipping out, try loosening the tension bolt pf your clipless pedals and find the right tension where you can clip out easily but not whilst pedalling.

Comment: Hi @Phoenix, biking to the office is not really a good idea, living in the Philippines. A lot of undisciplined drivers and whatnot. As for clipping, there are times that I can do it easily but then I sometimes panic clip out therefore resulting of me falling down.

Comment: Excellent advise loosening the tension on the clip, if possible.  To start with, it should be barely firm enough to hold you in while riding.  As soon as you get annoyed by it popping out while riding, tighten it a wee bit.

Comment: Hi also forgot that we already loosened the clip tension to it's max. I can easily clip in and clip out my right foot easily. But my left foot seems to be always confused when clipping out. Another question is clipless easier to use or should I stick to the standard?

Comment: @JetWaitforitTorres do you mean if normal pedals are easier to use ? of course. In case of clippers You just need to get used to them. Just do it on a still place. On your home for example until you learn to put and remove your leg staying still and without looking at the pedals.

Comment: Why do you say "increasing stamina and cadence cannot be trained at the same time"?

Comment: @altomnr I say that they cannot be trained at the same time because cadence is dependent on your power to weight ratio. Most of the time the higher that ratio is, the faster your cadence is. Stamina on the otherhand is a different thing. Stamina is how long you can last pushing at the same power on your bike for long distances, this means you can have a high power to weight ratio, but also be weak in stamina and can only go for only 30 to 40 mins max.

Comment: @JetWaitforitTorres Bro, I'm also from the Philippines. I go to class everyday on my bike, it's just a matter of bringing extra clothes with you and packing it nicely in a backpack. I suggest you watch "How to Pack your bag for work" by Global Cycling Network on YouTube. 

Comment: @Phoenix: I'd have to disagree with you on that; cadence has little to do with power to weight ratio - what you're likely seeing is that many cyclists with higher P/W ratios have adopted higher cadences while training to up their P/W. My team works with a lot of new cyclists and they're able to adopt higher cadences (90+ rpm), even though their P/W is very low. High cadence is effective because it shifts the load from mostly muscular (low cad.) to cardio (high cad.)...and since cardio doesn't fatigue as quickly as muscular, you can absolutely increase your stamina at the same time as cadence.

Comment: @Phoenix where are you from and where is your class?

Comment: @JetWaitforitTorres I'm from Pasay and my class is in Manila.

Comment: @Phoenix I see. I'm from Laguna and office is in Makati.

Comment: @JetWaitforitTorres well in that case it is a bit of a hassle. The only upside on that is you can do more training to increase endurance.  my answer still remains the same, biking is still a good way to get to work and it hits two of your concerns. Even if my work/class is somewhere else I would still bike going there.

Answer (score 0):

**Cadence** - the faster you can pedal while maintaining a good posture and bike control, the better.

The indicator that you're spinning too fast is bouncing in the saddle. If that happens go up a gear, or try to round-off your pedal stroke into a more circular shape.

If you have a good steady climb nearby, try doing it in a lower than normal gear, but turning the cranks faster.  Avoid bouncing in the saddle - its a waste of energy and makes your backside sore.  Plus it looks bad.

Comment: Note that the higher the cadence the more important it is to get your seat height right.